# redirecionar pagina de erro 404 com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quero saber como posso redirecionar uma mensagem de **erro 404** para o usuário. Neste caso necessito de um script exemplo, e como usar.

Vou simplificar um pouco o problema.

> O **erro 404** significa que a url do site/blog visitado não existem. Como fazer para redirecionar o **erro 404**, e depois de alguns segundos pra dentro da página `index.html`

Comment: Não seria só adicionar as linhas na própria página do 404? Não entendi direito a dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `setTimeout` e redirecionar para o `index.html`.

Na página 404 inclusa este script:

```
<script>
   window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.pt.stackoverflow.com"; },3000);
</script>
```